# Java ByteArray File Parsing

Tags: java, string, file, arrays

I have a file that contains a java ByteArray.

bytes.inc

```
byte MyByteArray[] = new byte[]
{
(byte) 0x4D,(byte) 0x5A,(byte) 0x50,(byte) 0x00,(byte) 0x02,(byte) 0x00,(byte) 0x00,
(byte) 0x00,(byte) 0x04,(byte) 0x00,(byte) 0x0F,(byte) 0x00,(byte) 0xFF,(byte) 0xFF,
(byte) 0x00,(byte) 0x00,(byte) 0xB8,(byte) 0x00,(byte) 0x00,(byte) 0x00,(byte) 0x00,
(byte) 0x00,(byte) 0x00,(byte) 0x00,(byte) 0x40,(byte) 0x00,(byte) 0x1A,(byte) 0x00,
(byte) 0x00,(byte) 0x00,(byte) 0x00,(byte) 0x00,(byte) 0x00,(byte) 0x00,(byte) 0x00,
(byte) 0x00,(byte) 0x00,(byte) 0x00,(byte) 0x00,(byte) 0x00,(byte) 0x00,(byte) 0x00,
(byte) 0x00,(byte) 0x00,(byte) 0x00,(byte) 0x00,(byte) 0x00,(byte) 0x00,(byte) 0x00,
(byte) 0x00,(byte) 0x00,(byte) 0x00,(byte) 0x00,(byte) 0x00,(byte) 0x00,(byte) 0x00,
(byte) 0x00,(byte) 0x00,(byte) 0x00,(byte) 0x00,(byte) 0x00,(byte) 0x01,(byte) 0x00,
(byte) 0x00,(byte) 0x00,(byte) 0x00,(byte) 0x00,
};
```

The full file (bytes.inc) is 283kb which is too much for the compiler to allow me to insert into a specific class. I have tried reading the file as just byte by byte then convert it from a string to an actual byte because reading files only produces strings, when I do that and convert a byte back it shows a textual representation of the byte, and not its actual conversion.
How can I go about getting the ability to produce the full ByteArray without including it into a huge method?

Answer (score 1):

One option is to store the actual bytes in a file and read them using `Files.readAllBytes(path)`

```
Path path = Paths.get("path/to/file");
byte[] bytes = Files.readAllBytes(path);
```

Another option is to keep the bytes as text in a file
 separated by `,` and use the following code:

```
FileReader file = new FileReader("bytes.txt");
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
scanner.useDelimiter(",");
ByteBuffer byteBuffer = new ByteBuffer(0);
while (scanner.hasNext()) {
    byteBuffer.append(Byte.decode(scanner.next().trim()));
}
scanner.close();
```

The byte file would look like:

```
0x4D,0x5A,0x50,0x00,0x02
```